# Woocommerce - Add single-product class to the body

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've trawled through a tonne of forums and nothing I find works. I'm using my own theme which is a blank one. I've impemented Woocommerce but I cant seem to get the body classes into the template

Desired

Categories to have the product-category class in the body tag
Products to have the single-product class in the body tag

Can anyone help as I'm feeling the results in finding are outdated

Comment: Are you not following WordPress [theming conventions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Classes) and using [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)? If you are, then you will get those classes by default.

Answer (score 2):

Open your theme and check in header.php whether your theme body  tag has 
body_class() function called or not. If not you can call it like this

```
<body <?php body_class( 'your-custom-class-name' ); ?>>
```

For more details, you can read WP codex here 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/